# Select specific names in R

Tags: r, select

I have columnA with a list of animals and columnB with a list of animals and description. I need to find which animals in ColumnA are not in animals in columnB.

What can I use to select the names of ColumnA that are only in ColumnB?

Example:

```
ColumnA   Cat     Dog      Bird      Fish

ColumnB  *&^Cat!167676fourlegs    90876Bird##wings     ***&&Dog
```

Thank you!

Comment: It's interesting that you claim these are *columns* (implying a single `data.frame`), yet `ColumnA` is length 4 and `ColumnB` is length 3. Next, your question appears to suggest strict equality but your sample data suggests pattern-matching (e.g., regex). What happens when `ColumnB` contains `"*!Cathode1234"*`, should it match `Cat`? What about `"&^CatDog9876"`?

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer, that's what I have... I've tried to find a method to show the animals that are not in Column A but I'm stuck. Ex."CatDog" would count as you can find it in Column A. Any other suggestion?

Comment: It would help to know the *real* structure of your data, since `data.frame`s in R cannot have varying lengths (technically it can happen, but almost always by design and after specific efforts to make it so). If you are dealing with two vectors (not columns), then please change the wording in your question. If you are dealing with a `data.frame`, then ... give a frame, ideally with `dput(x)` where `x` is a representative but small sample of your data, perhaps `dput(x[1:4,c("ColumnA","ColumnB")])`.

Comment: Further, are you hoping to find `Cat` in ColumnB, or are you extracting `c("Cat","fourlegs","Bird","winds","Dog")` from `ColumnB` and looking for those words in ColumnA?